# How to pass variable id with history.push()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks, tsx

I am using react-router library to navigate, and history.push() to navigate onClick. When user clicks on a row they will be navigated to 'otherPage'. In 'otherPage' I want to use the variable 'id'. How do I pass this variable?

```
function handleRowClick(id: number): void {
    // navigates user to another page
    history.push('/otherPage');
}
```

Comment: Please don't put "tags" in the title, that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
history.push(route, state);
```

The optional `state` param is an object with your custom routing params.

the `state` object is available here inside of your component (if not you can wrap it with [withRouter hoc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md))

```js
this.props.location.state
```

### Class Component

#### Hight Order Component

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
/* other dependencies */

class YourClassComponent {
  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;
    console.log(location.state);

    return (
      /* some jsx here */ 
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourClassComponent);
```

### Functional Component

#### Hight Order Component

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
/* other dependencies */

const YourFunctionalComponent = ({ location }) => {
  console.log(location.state);

  return (
    /* some jsx here */ 
  );
};

export withRouter(YourFunctionalComponent);
```

#### React hook

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
/* other dependencies */

const YourFunctionalComponent = ({ location } ) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.state);

  return (
    /* some jsx here */ 
  );
};
```

Comment: Alright thanks, but how do I use the variable inside 'otherPage' when using React Hooks?

Comment: @Io7 I added the info about `withRouter` hoc
I hope it will help :)